# Changing Y-axis of spritesheet with click to move

Tags: animation, xna, mouse, sprite-sheet

I'm new here and to programming. I have been searching for a while, though I can't find anything to help with the problem.

I'm trying to make my spritesheet cycle through the different walking frames of my spritesheet, I have done it easily with IsKeyDown but when it comes to using the mouse to walk somewhere it took me a while to nut out a 'bad' solution:

```
if (destination.X > position.X)                
                currentFrame.Y = 6;
            if (destination.X > position.X && destination.Y >= position.Y + 35)
                currentFrame.Y = 7;
            if (destination.X > position.X && destination.Y <= position.Y - 35)
                currentFrame.Y = 5;
```

It sort of works, but was wondering if there was a better work-around for this.
What I want is to be able to click on the game-screen and the appropriate sprite row be selected, relative to sprites current position and destination, to make it animate the proper way.

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I have searched around for a few hours before posting this and found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit unclear as to exactly what you are doing. Do you only have 2 sprites, one for left and one for right? Thats all i can see in your current code, but you are referring to animating. I am going to assume that you have a full set of sprites to animate walking, in which case I think this tutorial will cover what you need:

http://coderplex.blogspot.ca/2010/04/2d-animation-part-1-basics.html

(more specifically, part 4 of the tutorial: http://coderplex.blogspot.ca/2010/04/2d-animation-part-4-sprite-animation.html )

Basically, you are going to need to set timers to control the sprite animation, as with this type of mouse movement there is no more input (related to moving) between the time you click the mouse and the time the object gets to the destination. So you need to use a timer to determine when the next sprite in the walking animation should be called.

Alternatively, you could further elaborate on your if statements (if currentFrame = 1 then currentFrame = 2, if currentFrame = 2 then currentFrame = 3, etc), but it would be messy and pretty difficult to maintain if you ever make changes to the graphic or the way the sprite is pulled from the spritesheet. It also would most likely animate too fast, and you'd have to use timers to slow it down anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too sure how to really word it. My sprite-sheet is [9,8] with 8 directions of movement, and 9 frames of animation. Here is one of my keyboard if's;

Comment: Missed out on the 5 min edit rule and changed my explanation a bit.

Yeah, I'm not too sure how to really word it. My sprite-sheet is [9,8] with 8 directions of movement, and 9 frames of animation.

What I'm trying to find is if I click North of my sprite how to make my sprite-sheet change to the north row, I have it cycling through the 9 different sprites just not finding it easy to change the row of sprites to cycle through via mouse co-ordinates.

I will check out the link and thank-you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out I think. Here's my code (hoping it's formatted correctly. Sorry if I'm not meant to answer my own question, thought this might be helpful to someone else):

```
public Vector2 position = new Vector2(200, 200);
    Point frameSize = new Point(48, 92);
    Point currentFrame = new Point(0, 0);
    Point sheetSize = new Point(9, 8);
    float speed = 10;
    Vector2 direction;
    Vector2 destination;
    bool mousePressed = false;
    float difference;


    KeyboardState currentState;
    KeyboardState theKeyboardState;
    KeyboardState oldKeyboardState;

    enum State
    {
        Walking
    }

    State mcurrentState = State.Walking;

    TimeSpan nextFrameInterval =
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds((float)1 / 16);
    TimeSpan nextFrame;
    MouseState mouseState;
    MouseState oldState;

    public void Move()
    {
        direction = destination - position;
        direction.Normalize();
        position += direction * speed;

        float Xdistance = destination.X - position.X;
        float Ydistance = destination.Y - position.Y;

        difference = (float)Math.Atan2(Ydistance, Xdistance);

        float differ;
        differ = MathHelper.ToDegrees(difference);

        if (destination.X >= position.X || destination.X <= position.X)
        {                
            currentFrame.X++;
            if (currentFrame.X >= 9)
                currentFrame.X = 0;

            //down = 90dg
            if (differ >= 67.6 && differ <= 112.5)
                currentFrame.Y = 0;
            if (differ >= 112.6 && differ <= 157.5)
                currentFrame.Y = 1;
            if (differ >= 157.6 && differ <= 180 || differ >= -180 && differ <= -157.5)
                currentFrame.Y = 2;
            if (differ >= -157.4 && differ <= -112.5)
                currentFrame.Y = 3;
            if (differ >= -112.4 && differ <= -67.5)
                currentFrame.Y = 4;
            if (differ >= -67.4 && differ <= -22.5)
                currentFrame.Y = 5;
            if (differ >= -22.4 && differ <= 22.5)
                currentFrame.Y = 6;
            if (differ >= 22.6 && differ <= 67.5)
                currentFrame.Y = 7;
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
        currentState = Keyboard.GetState();
        theKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (mousePressed == true)
        {
            if (Vector2.DistanceSquared(destination, position) >= speed * speed)
            {
                Move();
            }
        }

        if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && oldState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
        {
            int mouseY = mouseState.Y;
            int mouseX = mouseState.X;

            destination = new Vector2(mouseX, mouseY);
            mousePressed = true;
        }

        oldState = mouseState;           

        if (mcurrentState == State.Walking)
        {
            #region KB animation

            if (currentState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            {
                mousePressed = false;
                currentFrame.X++;
                currentFrame.Y = 0;
                if (currentFrame.X >= 9)
                    currentFrame.X = 0;
                position.Y += speed;
            }

            if (currentState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                mousePressed = false;
                currentFrame.X++;
                currentFrame.Y = 4;
                if (currentFrame.X >= 9)
                    currentFrame.X = 0;
                position.Y -= speed;
            }

            if (currentState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            {
                mousePressed = false;
                currentFrame.X++;
                currentFrame.Y = 6;
                if (currentState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                    currentFrame.Y = 7;
                if (currentState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                    currentFrame.Y = 5;
                if (currentFrame.X >= 9)
                    currentFrame.X = 0;
                position.X += speed;
            }

            if (currentState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                mousePressed = false;
                currentFrame.X++;
                currentFrame.Y = 2;
                if (currentState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                    currentFrame.Y = 1;
                if (currentState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                    currentFrame.Y = 3;
                if (currentFrame.X >= 9)
                    currentFrame.X = 0;
                position.X -= speed;
            }
        }
        oldKeyboardState = theKeyboardState;
            #endregion

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D character)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        spriteBatch.Draw(character, position, new Rectangle(frameSize.X * currentFrame.X,
            frameSize.Y * currentFrame.Y, frameSize.X, frameSize.Y), Color.White, 0, new Vector2(frameSize.X / 2, frameSize.Y / 2), 1, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

        spriteBatch.End();
    }
```